# What is the difference can be tested between mapfile and mapfile -t?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Sample 1 with option t:

```
f(){
        mapfile -t aaa < /dev/stdin
        echo -e ${aaa[@]}
}
echo -e "a\nb\nc" | f
```

Sample 2 without option t:

```
f(){
        mapfile aaa < /dev/stdin
        echo -e ${aaa[@]}
}
echo -e "a\nb\nc" | f
```

The outputs are same:
`a b c`

EDIT:

Why are there two whitespaces in @cdarke's and @heemayl's answer?
`echo -e "a\nb\nc" | f2 | od -b`

```
0000000 141 012 040 142 012 040 143 012 012
0000011
```

Then I tried this: `echo -e "a\tb\tc" | f2 | od -b`

```
0000000 141 011 142 011 143 012 012
0000007
```

And there are no whitespaces.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2):

To see the difference quote `${aaa[@]}`:

```
echo -e "${aaa[@]}"
```

Without quoting the expansion is being subjected to word splitting according to `IFS` (and pathname expansion too). As the elements (strings) contain newlines, these will go through word splitting.

**Example:**

```
$ f() { mapfile -t aaa < /dev/stdin; echo -e "${aaa[@]}" ;}
$ echo -e "a\nb\nc" | f
a b c

$ g() { mapfile aaa < /dev/stdin; echo -e "${aaa[@]}" ;}
$ echo -e "a\nb\nc" | g
a
 b
 c
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `echo`:

```
f1(){
    mapfile -t aaa < /dev/stdin
    echo -e "${aaa[@]}"       # note the quotes
}
echo -e "a\nb\nc" | f1

f2(){
    mapfile aaa < /dev/stdin
    echo -e "${aaa[@]}"       # note the quotes
}
echo -e "a\nb\nc" | f2
```

Gives:

```
a b c
a
 b
 c
```

In the second case, without the quotes, the newlines are seen as whitespace.

Comment: Why are there two whitespace?  
echo -e "a\nb\nc" | f2 | od -b  
```
    0000000 141 012 040 142 012 040 143 012 012
    0000011
```

Comment: Do you mean the two newlines at the end?  Each `echo` adds a newline, one in the caller and one in the `f2` function.  Change to `echo -en "${aaa[@]}"  ` to suppress the extra newline.